# What is meaning of "parameter optimization of SVM by PSO"?

Tags: optimization, machine-learning, svm

I can change parameters C and epsilon manually to obtain an optimised result, but I found that there is parameter optimization of SVM by PSO (or any other optimization algorithm).  There is no algorithm.  What does it mean: how can PSO automatically optimize the SVM parameters?  I read several papers on this topic, but I'm still not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Particle Swarm Optimization is a technique that uses the ML parameters (SVM parameters, in your case) as its features.

Each "particle" in the swarm is characterized by those parameter values.  For instance, you might have initial coordinates of

```
   degree  epsilon  gamma   C
p1    3     0.001    0.25  1.0
p2    3     0.003    0.20  0.9
p3    2     0.0003   0.30  1.2
p4    4     0.010    0.25  0.5
...
pn   ...........................
```

The "fitness" of each particle (p1-p4 shown here out of a population of **n** particles) is measured by the accuracy of the resulting model: the PSO algorithm trains and tests a model for each particle, returning that model's error rate as the value analogous to that from the training loss function (which it how the value is computed).

On each iteration, particles move toward the fittest neighbours.  The process repeats until a maximum (hopefully the global one) appears as a convergence point.  This process is simply one from the familiar gradient descent family.

There are two basic PSO variants.  In **gbest** (global best), every particle affects every other particle, sort of a universal gravitation principle.  It converges quickly, but may well miss a global max in favor of a local max that happened to be nearer to the swarm's original center.  In **lbest** (local best), a particle responds to only its **k** closest neighbors.  This can form localized clusters; it converges more slowly, but is more likely to find the global max in a non-convex space.

---

I'll try to briefly explain enough to answer your clarification questions.  If that doesn't work, I'm afraid you'll probably have to find someone to discuss this in front of a white board.

To use PSO, you have to decide which SVM parameters you'll try to optimize, and how many particles you want to use.  PSO is a meta-algorithm, so its features are the SVM parameters.  The PSO parameters are population (how many particles you want to use, update neighbourhood (**lbest** size and a distance function; **gbest** is the all-inclusive case), and velocity (learning rate for the SVM parameters).

For a bit of illustration, let's assume the particle table above, extended to a population of 20 particles.  We'll use **lbest** with a neighbourhood of 4, and a velocity of 0.1.  We choose (randomly, in a grid, or however we think might give us nice results) the initial values of degree, epsilon, gamma, and C for each of the 20 particles.

```
Each iteration of PSO works like this:
    # Train the model described by each particle's "position"
    For each of the 20 particles:
        Train an SVM with the SVM input and the given parameters.
        Test the SVM; return the error rate as the PSO loss function value.

    # Update the particle positions
    for each of the 20 particles:
        find the nearest 4 neighbours (using the PSO distance function)
        identify the neighbour with the lowest loss (SVM's error rate).
        adjust this particle's features (degree, epsilon, gamma, C) 0.1 of the way toward that neighbour's features.  0.1 is our learning rate / velocity.  (Yes, I realize that changing degree is not likely to happen (it's a discrete value) without a special case in the update routine.

Continue iterating through PSO until the particles have converged to your liking.
```

**gbest** is simply **lbest** with an infinite neighbourhood; in that case, you don't need a distance function on the particle space.

Comment: I am unable to get your answer. In PSO there is velocity and position which changes with iteration. So with this How can I optimise the SVM parameters using PSO so that I get better result. Lastly I am not able to understand table.

Comment: Then please explain just where and what part you don't understand.  SO is not a tutorial site, not a place for me to post a one-hour lecture on the topic.

Comment: I have already stated in my comment that in equation of PSO we have terms velocity and position. We take initial population. But when we are optimizing 2 parameter what will be population, position and velocity. Take for example C and epsilon parameter in SVM or C, epsilon and gamma parameter in SVM. How C, epsilon (or C,epsilon and gamma) can be described  in terms of position, velocity and population? Also how we can link parameter optimization with gbest and lbest. Thanks

Comment: The SVM parameters and PSO parameters cannot be described in terms of one another; they are not in the same algorithm space.  This separation is the subject of my answer's first sentence.

Comment: I'm not sure how you intend to "link" parameter optimization -- **lbest** and **gbest** are two variants of the algorithm that updates SVM parameters from one PSO iteration to the next.

Comment: αnewi=w×αoldi+c1×rand1×(pbesti−βoldi)+c2×rand2×(gbesti−βoldi)

    αi and βi are parameters chosen by the user. Is this right to find optimal values of α(C in SVM) and β(epsilon in SVM) with respect to PSO?